# Villain uses hero to kill people by hitting them with him

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember watching a series/movie (or maybe even read it on a manga – possibly Gantz, but I am not sure) where the villain just grabs the hero, who doesn't want to kill innocents, and uses him physically to kill others.

At one point, they fly through a subway and the villain just uses the hero to tear people apart. The villain holds him and uses him as a shield as he breaks through the cars of a subway; as people collide with the unbreakable hero, they get torn apart due to their regular bodies.

I think it was animated, given the gore involved, but it is just a vague memory I have.

Comment: It's not a manga. It's a comic published by Image. (And yes, the comic is awesome - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invincible_(comics))

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This could be [*Invincible*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invincible_(TV_series)), an animated series on Amazon Prime Video (based on the Image Comics series of the same name by Robert Kirkman). The animated series premiered in March 2021, but the comic has been around since 2003.

There is a scene in the season 1 finale where the villain uses the hero exactly as described:

Comment: By the guy who created The Walking Dead.

Comment: that's insane considering their relationship as well (not really a spoiler if you've seen the first episode)

Comment: Just watched this a couple days ago, the first season was awesome.

Comment: The Villain looks like Lukashenko with more hair.

Comment: well that was horrifying